# Update date values based on duplicated values and previous ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, for-loop

It's the first time I post here and it is a tricky question, basically I have this table in which I have a patient that has taken a certain medication, but there are certain dates that are missing because the patient can buy several boxes at a time, so I basically duplicated the rows based on the number of boxes the patient bought. This leads me to this table:

[image]

You can see that the duplicated rows all bought enough medication for two months, in this case.

What I need to do is transform the dates in a way that they are in sequence, but I can only o this when the dates are duplicated so I don't change the original data of other patients.

I have tried a for loop like this

```
for index,row in output_table_1.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        next
    elif output_table_1.loc[index, 'Date'] == output_table_1.loc[index-1, 'Date']:
        output_table_1.at[index, 'Date']  = row['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=28)
    else: 
        output_table_1.at[index, 'Date']  = row['Date']
```

But it does not give me what I need, basically I need it to change the data based on previous information like this:

Original data:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2017-01-31 |
| 7 | 2017-01-31 |
| 8 | 2017-02-28 |
| 9 | 2017-02-28 |
| 10 | 2017-03-31 |
| 11 | 2017-03-31 |
| 12 | 2017-04-30 |
| 13 | 2017-04-30 |

First loop:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2017-01-31 |
| 7 | 2017-02-31 |
| 8 | 2017-02-28 |
| 9 | 2017-02-28 |
| 10 | 2017-03-31 |
| 11 | 2017-03-31 |
| 12 | 2017-04-30 |
| 13 | 2017-04-30 |

Second loop:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2017-01-31 |
| 7 | 2017-02-31 |
| 8 | 2017-03-28 |
| 9 | 2017-02-28 |
| 10 | 2017-03-31 |
| 11 | 2017-03-31 |
| 12 | 2017-04-30 |
| 13 | 2017-04-30 |

Third loop:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2017-01-31 |
| 7 | 2017-02-31 |
| 8 | 2017-03-28 |
| 9 | 2017-04-28 |
| 10 | 2017-03-31 |
| 11 | 2017-03-31 |
| 12 | 2017-04-30 |
| 13 | 2017-04-30 |

Final Output:

|  | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 2017-01-31 |
| 7 | 2017-02-31 |
| 8 | 2017-03-28 |
| 9 | 2017-04-28 |
| 10 | 2017-05-31 |
| 11 | 2017-06-31 |
| 12 | 2017-07-30 |
| 13 | 2017-08-30 |

And so on.

Comment: But, "2017-02-31" is a corrected date?

Comment: Thank you for your question. So basically the patient bought enough medication for two months, so I need to extend it enough times. As you can see in the table image he bought two boxes per month which means that he had enough for one year, that is what I need. Basically he needs to be in the table, with that particular medication for 12 months. The table also has other patients. Edit: grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still looking for a solution, you could try the following:

```
def adjust(ser):
    if (ser == ser.shift()).any():
        one_month = pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
        last_month = ser.iat[0]
        for i, month in ser.iloc[1:].items():
            if month <= last_month:
                ser.at[i] = last_month + one_month
            last_month = ser.at[i]
    return ser

df.Date = df.groupby(["Pt", "Drg name"]).Date.transform(adjust)
```

Assumptions:

- All of your dates are month end dates (looks like it in the sample).
- Your example is not representative, in the sense that there could be "gaps" in the multiple date series: See the last group in my example below. If that's not nescesarry, then there's a simpler solution.

I've added the condition `if (ser == ser.shift()).any()` to avoid unnecessary work. If you have to adjust the majority of the groups then it's probably better to remove it.

Result for

```
df = 
      Pt       Date Drg name
0   Pt A 2017-01-31    Drg A
1   Pt A 2017-02-28    Drg A
2   Pt A 2017-03-31    Drg A
3   Pt A 2017-04-30    Drg A
4   Pt A 2017-05-31    Drg A
5   Pt A 2017-06-30    Drg A
6   Pt A 2017-01-31    Drg B
7   Pt A 2017-01-31    Drg B
8   Pt A 2017-02-28    Drg B
9   Pt A 2017-02-28    Drg B
10  Pt A 2017-03-31    Drg B
11  Pt A 2017-03-31    Drg B
12  Pt A 2017-04-30    Drg B
13  Pt A 2017-04-30    Drg B
14  Pt B 2020-11-30    Drg B
15  Pt B 2020-11-30    Drg B
16  Pt B 2021-02-28    Drg B
17  Pt B 2021-02-28    Drg B
```

is

```
      Pt       Date Drg name
0   Pt A 2017-01-31    Drg A
1   Pt A 2017-02-28    Drg A
2   Pt A 2017-03-31    Drg A
3   Pt A 2017-04-30    Drg A
4   Pt A 2017-05-31    Drg A
5   Pt A 2017-06-30    Drg A
6   Pt A 2017-01-31    Drg B
7   Pt A 2017-02-28    Drg B
8   Pt A 2017-03-31    Drg B
9   Pt A 2017-04-30    Drg B
10  Pt A 2017-05-31    Drg B
11  Pt A 2017-06-30    Drg B
12  Pt A 2017-07-31    Drg B
13  Pt A 2017-08-31    Drg B
14  Pt B 2020-11-30    Drg B
15  Pt B 2020-12-31    Drg B
16  Pt B 2021-02-28    Drg B
17  Pt B 2021-03-31    Drg B
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved and even made the solution more performant! You're a life saver!